# Ruby: efficient way to sum elements grouped by the first element of each subarray

Tags: ruby

I have a json structure:

```
[["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0], ["item2", 1, 0], ["item2", 1, 0],["item3", 1, 0],["item4", 1, 0],["item5", 1, 0]..]]
```

right now I'm summing them manually thru loops to get the following

```
[["item1", 3, 0], ["item2", 2, 0], ["item4", 1, 0], ["item5", 1, 0]]
```

is there another way to do it? I looked at the array module in Ruby but I'm not sure if there exist another way to do this ...

EDIT: this is what I was doing: for here I'm summing the second item only

```
    @object = []
    @stat = Hash.new

    @data.each do |d|     

       if @object.include?(d[0])
         @stat [d[0]] += d[2]
       else
         @object << d[0]
         @stat[ d[0] ] = d[2]
       end
   end
```

Edit2:

I timed the one liner solution and compared it to my own

oneliner: 0.005 
mine: 0.007

This is what I ended up using at the end:

```
data.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |stat, item| 
    if item[0] =~ /[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][a-z]/ # extra stuff that I needed 
      item[0] = item[0][0..8]
      stat[item[0]] += item[2]
    end
    stat
  }
```

Thanks everyone I learned a lot.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the code that you're using, not a paraphrase or description.

Comment: Don't forget that Array includes the Enumerable module. It has a lot of good methods to look into as well.

Comment: Hi Newbie! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [Stack Overflow Newbie Manual](http://grahn.us/projects/stack-overflow.php?name=Newbie). It will help you ask better questions and get better answers. BTW, That's the actual name of it. I didn't change it just for you... :-P

Comment: I added my code. I had to strip some stuff from it

Comment: Andy Lester what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner which produces an array (as in the example):

```
result = array.inject(Hash.new(0)){|h,item|h[item.first]+=item[2];h}.to_a
```

If you want the results in a hash instead of an array, just leave off the `.to_a`

Comment: Were you golfing here? :P

Comment: hey thank you, how to get this format instead {"item1"=>20, "item2"=>23, "item3"=>20, ... } I'll accept it if you can give this format, otherwise I'm sticking to my old for loop

Comment: simple, remove the `.to_a` at the end

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
result = array.uniq.each do |a|
  a[1] = array.count { |b| b[0] == a[0] }
end
```

You could also use the chunk method as mentioned above:

```
result = []
array.chunk { |k| k }.each { |k, v| result << [k[0], v.length, k[2]] }
```

It's up to you which you like better. I prefer the first.

Comment: I too prefer the first, but would be inclined to use, 'array.uniq.map...'.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `map`?

Comment: Just because my brain is faster at deciphering array.uniq.map {|a| [a.first, array.count {|b| b.first == a.first}, a.last].  ymmv.  btw, two reasons I prefer uniqueing to chunking here is that the former does not depend on the order of the elements in array and does not require array[i].last to be the same for all i.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) method. This doesn't get your exact answer, but should get you there:

```
a=[["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0], ["item2", 1, 0], ["item2", 1, 0], ["item3", 1, 0], ["item4", 1, 0], ["item5", 1, 0]]

a.chunk { |k| k }.each { |k, v| p [k[0], v.length] }

["item1", 3]
["item2", 2]
["item3", 1]
["item4", 1]
["item5", 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it's efficient, but its less code

```rb
require 'matrix'#not a gem, stdlib
munge = Hash.new(Matrix.zero(1,2))
array = [
  ["item1", 3, 0],
  ["item1", 1, 0],
  ["item1", 1, 0],
  ["item2", 5, 0],
  ["item1", 1, 0],
  ["item4", 1, 0],
  ["item3", 1, 0],
  ["item4", 1, 0]
]
array.each do |(key,a,b)|
  munge[key] += Matrix[[a, b]]
end
# {
#   "item1"=>Matrix[[6, 0]],
#   "item2"=>Matrix[[5, 0]],
#   "item4"=>Matrix[[2, 0]],
#   "item3"=>Matrix[[1, 0]],
# }
#force back into array
munge.each_key { |key| munge[key] = munge[key].row(0).to_a }
```

edit it slightly and it can handle a varying number of "columns"

```rb
require 'matrix'
array = [
  ["item1", 3, 0, 3, 0],
  ["item1", 1, 0, 1, 0],
  ["item1", 1, 1, 1, 7],
  ["item2", 5, 0, 5, 0],
  ["item1", 1, 0, 1, 2],
  ["item4", 1, 0, 5, 8],
  ["item3", 1, 0, 1, 0],
  ["item4", 1, 0, 1, 0]
]
munge = Hash.new(Matrix.zero(1, array.first.size - 1))
array.each do |(key,*arr)|
  munge[key] += Matrix[arr]
end
#{
#  "item1"=>Matrix[[6, 1, 6, 9]],
#  "item2"=>Matrix[[5, 0, 5, 0]],
#  "item4"=>Matrix[[2, 0, 6, 8]],
#  "item3"=>Matrix[[1, 0, 1, 0]]
#}
```

Answer (score 1):

A completion of Spencer's answer, but `#chunk` is indeed the right answer here.

If I interpret the question correctly, you want to sum positions 1 and 2 of every array that has a common value in position 0. The provided data has uniform values, but my solution doesn't assumt that. You first just need to chunk by `position[0]`:

```
a=[["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0], ["item2", 1, 0], ["item2", 1, 0], ["item3", 1, 0], ["item4", 1, 0], ["item5", 1, 0]]

chunked = a.chunk { |k| k[0] }
# => [["item1", [["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0]]], ["item2", [["item2", 1, 0], ["item2", 1, 0]]], ["item3", [["item3", 1, 0]]], ["item4", [["item4", 1, 0]]], ["item5", [["item5", 1, 0]]]]
```

Then, you can sum the values in each chunk. This is easily done by taking each chunk, transposing it to get all values at a given index in an array, then summing the interesting arrays via inject:

```
chunked.map {|k, v| t = v.transpose; [k, t[1].inject(:+), t[2].inject(:+)] }
# => [["item1", 3, 0], ["item2", 2, 0], ["item3", 1, 0], ["item4", 1, 0], ["item5", 1, 0]]
```

Combined, this is as simple as:

```
a.chunk {|k| k[0] }.map do |k, v|
  t = v.transpose
  [k, t[1].inject(:+), t[2].inject(:+)]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but if you wanted to do it with the data in its current form you could use `group_by`:

```
data.group_by(&:first).reduce([]) do |acc, (k, v)|
  acc + [[ k, v.map { |x| x[1] }.reduce(:+), v.map { |x| x[2] }.reduce(:+) ]]
end
```

But Ruby is an OO language! It shines the most when you make use of it in this way :-). So you might want to consider creating model classes for your data to make working with them read a bit nicer. You can use a gem I co-wrote called '[id](https://github.com/rsslldnphy/id)' (as in id, ego, superego) to easily create models from Ruby hashes if you like:

```
require 'id'

class Item
  include Id::Model

  field :name
  field :x
  field :y

  def + other
    fail unless name == other.name
    Item.new(name: name, x: x + other.x, y: y + other.y)
  end

end

items = data.map { |(name, x, y)| Item.new(name: name, x: x, y: y) }
```

Then the above `group_by` code becomes a lot more readable, and starts to better express its intent:

```
items.group_by(&:name).values.map { |v| v.reduce(:+) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0], ["item1", 1, 0], ["item2", 1, 0], 
     ["item2", 1, 0], ["item3", 1, 0], ["item4", 1, 0], ["item5", 1, 0]]
```

To get desired result you can either use [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
a.inject({}) {|h,e| h[e[0]].nil? ? h[e[0]] = [e[1],e[2]] : h[e[0]] = [h[e[0]][0] + e[1], h[e[0]][2] + e[2]];h }

#=> {"item1"=>[3, 0], "item2"=>[2, 0], "item3"=>[1, 0], "item4"=>[1, 0], "item5"=>[1, 0]}
```

or [group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) with [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

```
a.group_by {|i| i[0]}.values.map {|v| v.transpose.map {|x| x[0].class == String ? next : x.reduce(:+)}.map {|x| x.nil? ? v[0][0] : x } }

#=> [["item1", 3, 0], ["item2", 2, 0], ["item3", 1, 0], ["item4", 1, 0], ["item5", 1, 0]]
```